# Emacs: Is it possible to assign a number-key kb shortcut to a buffer?

Tags: emacs

I use desktop sessions to save project state between loads. Sometimes I am working on a feature that is shared between a few buffers, and would love to assign a quick keyboard shortcut like -# to a buffer. Then I could switch between a fe buffers by hitting cmd-1, cmd-2, cmd-3, etc. Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this code for this purpose:

```lisp
(require 'bookmark)

(defvar zz-minibuffer-map (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-must-match-map)
  "Keymap for `bookmark-do-quick-jump'")

(define-key zz-minibuffer-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'zz-self-insert-complete-and-exit)
(define-key zz-minibuffer-map " " "-")

(defvar zz-display-function nil)

(defun zz-self-insert-complete-and-exit (n)
  (interactive "p")
  (self-insert-command n)
  (ignore-errors
    (completion--do-completion nil 'expect-exact))
  (let ((candidates (completion-all-sorted-completions)))
    (cond
      ((null candidates)
       (backward-delete-char-untabify 1)
       (minibuffer-complete))
      ((eq 1 (safe-length candidates))
       (minibuffer-complete-and-exit)))))

;;;###autoload
(defun zz-bookmark-jump (bookmark)
  "Jump to specified bookmark with auto-completion and auto-acceptance."
  (interactive
   (list
    (if (window-minibuffer-p)
        (error "Already in minibuffer")
     (let ((minibuffer-local-must-match-map zz-minibuffer-map))
       (completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " bookmark-alist nil t)))))
  (ignore-errors
    (bookmark-jump bookmark zz-display-function)))
```

Just bind `zz-bookmark-jump` to what you want, say <kbd>M-m</kbd>.
Now, if you name a bookmark as `1...`, where `...` is anything you want, and no other
bookmarks start with `1`, <kbd>M-m 1</kbd> will jump to that bookmark.

Here are some of my bookmarks for reference:

```
b:  .bashrc                 ~/.bashrc
e:  .emacs                  ~/.conf.d/.emacs
h:  hooks.el                   - no file -
L:  main.cc                 ~/Dropbox/source/c++/lattice/main.cc
m:  magit                      - no file -
q:   *scratch*                 - no file -
s:  source                  ~/Dropbox/source/
```

I like to add `:` to make them look nice visually when I call `bookmark-bmenu-list`.

Comment: Totally awesome, worked exactly as described with no lips problems. And for an emacs lover that for some reason hates to love elisp, working easy is key. Cheers!

Comment: One addition, this works really well, although it would be really nice if it would remember the last position in the file, instead of always jumping back to the bookmarked position. thoughts?

Comment: You could just reset the bookmark with `set-bookmark`. There's
tab-completion for known bookmark names. Otherwise, just keep the
buffer open if you want to keep the point position. With features like `helm-semantic` there's really no point to keeping the position in file.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) then you can use [**desktop bookmarks**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#DesktopBookmarks).  "Jumping" to such a bookmark restores the saved desktop - each bookmark refers to a particular desktop file.
Bookmarks are persistent.

A bookmark name can use any characters - it could be `1` or `9` or `312`.  You can bind a single key (including a digit key, if you like) to the command that jumps to a bookmark whose name you enter (with completion).

You can also easily define a command that jumps to a given bookmark.  And you can bind such a command to any single key you like: `1`, `2`,... or `-1`, `-2`,... (though that might not be a great idea ;-)).

(FWIW, a command *name* must be a symbol name, a symbol name must have symbol characters, and it cannot have the syntax of a number (which `2` and `-2` do).  So you could name commands `a1`, `a2`,... or `_1`, `_2`,... or `-a1`, `-a2`,....  But you are anyway unlikely to call such commands by their names.)

---

***UPDATE***

If you just want to switch/navigate among the files or buffers of a project, **without** closing other buffers etc. then look for project-support Emacs features and extensions.  There are plenty available, including some (such as Dired) that come with vanilla Emacs.

With **Bookmark+**, for example, you can use bookmarks of various types, including the following, to help manage software projects:

- **Dired** buffers, with specific sets of files and subdirectories
  that are marked or omitted, and using specific listing switches.
- `*Bookmark List*` buffers, with specific sets of bookmarks that
  are marked or hidden.
- Multiple alternative **bookmark files**.  For example, use a
  different one for each project.  Or use different ones for
  subprojects and use them together for a full project.
- **DeskTops** (already mentioned), which include sets of variables and visited buffers
  and files.
- [**Sequence bookmarks**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus#FunctionSequenceVarlistBookmarks), which *combine* other bookmarks.

You can also associate **tags**, in the [delicious](http://delicious.com) sense, with most
types of bookmarks.  (Such tags are unrelated to the Emacs
source-code tags that use TAGS files.)  A bookmark can have any
number of tags, and multiple bookmarks can have the same tag,
which means you can use them to organize their target objects.
And tags can be more than just names: they can be user-defined
*attributes*, with Emacs-Lisp objects as their values.

These and other **Bookmark+** features give you different ways to
save, restore, filter, access, and otherwise organize projects, as
collections of information about source-code components and
related software.

[**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) enhances access to such **Bookmark+** features, and it provides additional [project-support features](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects).

Comment: It seems like that is pretty close to what I want, although I would just like to show a buffer with <cmd>-1, and then show another with buffer <cmd>-2. Also, if I do this without switching desktops for each file then all the other buffers in the project are easily accessible by the usual named route.

It seems like with some elisp (of which I know none) something to assign a number or key combo to the command to show a buffer would be great as long as the buffer-to-number bindings were easy to set on the fly. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Not sure I understand all you've written. Sounds like `<cmd>` is a pseudo-function key (I'm not familiar with that one), and you want to use it as a prefix key. That's not a problem. I don't get your 2nd sentence - switch desktops only when you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) <cmd> is the apple key, sort of like hitting alt on windows. As I understand it switching desktops, whether with Bookmarks+ or otherwise, will close all buffers and re-open the ones stored in the recalled desktop session. This is a bit overkill for me since I just want to quickly show / hide certain buffers *within* the session. If I am misunderstanding this notion of desktops then this may change.

Comment: For example, when adding a feature to a wordpress theme, I will need to quickly switch between the same relevant html/css/js files for that feature, say once every 10 seconds or so. As I do that I also want to leave the rest of the buffers in the project open since I need to switch to one or the other of them every few minutes or so. All the while my "desktop" session is remembering the buffers and cursor position for *all* of the above buffers.

Basically this means having kb shortcuts to quickly switch between a few file tabs on an IDE without having to close and re-open my project to do so.

Comment: Changing desktops does not start a new Emacs session. But yes, it can change which buffers are displayed etc. Apparently you are just looking for a way to switch among the buffers or files of a particular project, without affecting other buffers that might exist. If so, please edit your question - you will get entirely different answers from people. There are ***lots*** of different ways to navigate among the files or buffers of a project.

Comment: Thank you again for your responses. After re-reading my question, I'm having trouble seeing the irrelevant language, with the exception of specifying to show/hide a buffer. For my own education, could your provide specifics as well as an example for how I could have improved my question?

Comment: Your question explicitly asks about switching among Emacs **desktops**, presumably as defined by library `desktop.el`. My impression after your comments is that you do *not* want that, because switching to a different desktop might change the set of buffers available/displayed. My impression is that you want only a way to switch among the files of another given project, without affecting any other buffers that might already exist.